# How can I map image(s) to functional component using props to pull data from array in App state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been at this for hours and need help as I feel like this is a really silly mistake! I'm trying to pull an image from the App component into my about page and I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am still learning ReactJS and also, any resources for learning this stuff on your own would be huge.

App.js:

```js
import AboutPage from "./pages/AboutPage";
import bentleyImg from "./assets/images/about-image.jpg";

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        headerLinks: [...],
        home: {
     ...
        },
        about: {
            images: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    src: bentleyImg,
                    title: 'Bentley',
                    description: 'Who doesn\'t love a cute dog pic?'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

AboutPage.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import Content from '../components/Content';

function AboutPage(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Hero title={props.title} />
            <Content>
                <div className="">
                    {props.about.images.map(({ id, src, title, description }) => <img key={id} src={src} title={title} alt={description} />)}
                </div>
            </Content>
        </div >
    );
}

export default AboutPage;
```

Comment: Could you share full app.js code? I 'd like to know how it is passing images to the about page component.

Comment: Is you component used like `<AboutPage about={this.state.about} ... />`?

Comment: Most likely `props.about` is undefined inside `AboutPage`. Make sure you're passing the prop correctly (there isn't enough code included in your example to know for sure)

Comment: I think the `about` is being set asynchronously , hence would be `undefined` when the component first mounts .